# update pgrouting from 2.0.0 to 2.2.0 due to malfunctioning

Tags: pgrouting, update

I have postgresql 9.1 and postgis 2.0 on ubuntu 12.04 currently installed, but when I try to execute the following command:

```
psql -d routing_test
ALTER EXTENSION pgrouting UPDATE TO "2.2.0";
```

output is the following:

```
ERROR:  extension "pgrouting" has no update path from version "2.0.0" to version "2.2.0"
```

Here is a screenshot from a bug in version 2.0.0, which I hope to fix with updating:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure you have pgrouting 2.2.0 installed, you might have a newer or older.

If you do:

```
ALTER EXTENSION pgrouting UPDATE;
```

It will update to latest version you have installed.

Alternatively you could just drop and recreate. It will warn if you have dependencies on pgrouting and won't allow drop.